# coordinate free Euler-Lagrange

Tags: calculus-of-variations

The variational approach is to seek critical points in terms 
the Euler-Lagrange variational derivatives 
$E_a(S_0)$ of a local function $S_0.$ The zero locus does not depend 
on coordinates. Where is there a similalry coordinate free
description of the corresponding Jacobian ideal?